# Add columns from an old dataset to a new one

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have the following dataset:

```
df=pd.read_csv('/path/text.csv')
```

that has columns `A B C D` (shown by using `print(df.columns)`)

What I have tried to do is to create new columns using columns from that file as follows:

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    parsed=urlparse(row['B'])
    netloc.append(parsed.netloc) # E
    paths.append(parsed.path) # F
```

What I would like to do is to manage this dataset including the new columns created (`E` and `F`)but also the old ones and saved this dataset as both `data frame` and `csv` (since it is very large, it could be useful to keep a copy in memory). My expected output would be a dataset with `6` columns `(A B C D E F)`, `4` from the old dataset and `2` from the new one.

How could I do to include columns `A B C D` in the new dataset and save it in both formats?

I tried with

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame({"A": a, "B" : b, "C" : c, "D" : d, "E": e, "F": f})
dataset.to_csv('path/text_1.csv', mode='w', header=True, index=False)
```

but I got error that B is not defined (`NameError: name 'B' is not defined`).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the function merge would be helpful for you.

If you have two dataframes you can "join" them vertically or horizontally. Merge can help you to join horizontally. The function should be used this way:

```
df1.merge(df2, left_on='lkey', right_on='rkey')
```

What you should consider is the field names of both dataframes.